# How to write a script for Wolfram SystemModeler to run several simulations?

Tags: modelica, wolfram-language, systemmodeler

I want to run around 100 simulations with my model changing two parameters `f` and `TLoad`and track the changes on the phase currents `currentSensor.i[1]` etc.

Now I'm stuck with the documentation on the Wolfram website because there is no definite explanation on how to use scripting with the SystemModeler. I found for example this [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GettingStartedWithModelSimulationAndAnalysis.html) on the Wolfram site with some code but no explanation in which commandline I should use it.

I downloaded the WolframScript program and tried to open my model with `wolframscript -file SMPM_VoltageSource_Inverter.mo` but it says `ToExpression::sntx: Invalid syntax in or before ...` eventhouh my model simulates totally fine and without any errors in the SimulationCenter.

Can someone explain to me:

- Is it possible to write scripts ?

If Yes:

- How can I simulate my model?
- How can I do a parameter sweep of `f` and `TLoad`? Is it as described in the link?
- Is it possible to export data of `currentSensor.i[1]` as a csv-file? And how to?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1792888).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about wolfram sorry, but for OpenModelica the following works:

```
// to load Model from file use
// loadFile("fileName.mo");

loadString("
model M
  parameter Real a = 1;
  Real x;
equation
  x = a * sin(time);
end M;
"); getErrorString();

buildModel(M); getErrorString();

for a in {1,2,3,4} loop
  str_a := String(a); getErrorString(); 

  system("./M -override a=" + str_a); getErrorString();
  // for windows use 
  //system("M.exe -override a=" + str_a); getErrorString();

  system("mv M_res.mat " + "M_" + str_a + ".mat");
end for;
```

Put this in a file named for example `model.mos` and call it from terminal or command line, depending on your os, with `omc model.mos` if you have OpenModelica installed. this should generate a csv.

EDIT: I realized the original just saves the last value of x, you might want the full output. Therefore i changed the `.mos`-file. Each different result will be saved in a different file, if you want to change it to csv you just have to change the generated xml.

Comment: Unrelated thought: Why is it that you have to postfix most statements in mos with `getErrorString()`? This seems awfully redundant. I am curious why those errors don't automatically get e.g. returned, or emitted to stderr or as an exception/similar mechanism?

Comment: Sometimes you don't want the errors and warnings to be emitted because you know they are not relevant for your case and too verbose. But maybe it would have been a better design decision to have a ``suppressErrorString()``  command instead.

Comment: I see, thanks. yeah, or configurable logging levels like e.g. in Python...